Does dotnet HubConnection supports multiple handlers registration?
I am trying to register multiple handlers for a SignalR hubconnection like this:
    _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithNoCertificateValidation(uri)
        .WithAutomaticReconnect()
        .Build();

    _hubConnection.On<TeamUpdatedEvent>(TeamHub.Methods.TeamUpdated,
        async evt =>
        {
            await UpdateUserTeams(evt.TeamId);
        });
    
    _hubConnection.On<TeamCreatedEvent>(TeamHub.Methods.TeamCreated,
        async evt =>
        {
            await UpdateUserTeams(evt.TenantId);
        });
    
    if (_hubConnection.State == HubConnectionState.Disconnected)
    {
        await _hubConnection.StartAsync();
        if (Teams is { Count: > 0 })
        {
            foreach (var teamId in Teams.Select(x => x.Id))
            {
                await _hubConnection.InvokeAsync(BaseHub.BaseMethods.RegisterToGroup, teamId);
            }
        }
    }

It seems the handler for TeamCreatedEvent is not getting called while the handler for TeamUpdatedEvent it is.
Multiple handlers on the same SignalR connection are not supported?

Hi @Mihaimyh, SignalR supports multiple handlers on the same connection, so registering handlers for both TeamUpdatedEvent and TeamCreatedEvent should work. Could you pls add logging within your SignalR handlers to confirm whether the TeamCreatedEvent handler is even being invoked. It is better for you to share the server side code and how do you register the handler.
